# Adding arrows to a parametric plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following plot

```
Show[Graphics[Axes -> True], ParametricPlot[al[t], {t, 0, 1}], 
 ParametricPlot[be[t], {t, 0, 1}]]
```

where `al[t]` and `be[t]` are parametric plots of a BezierFunction.

I would like to add arrows to the midpoint of the parametric plots. I have tried using the Arrow command but this does not work. Is there anyway to do this easily?

Comment: It would be nice to have a working example. Without that, consider something like: `ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /. Line[x__] :> Arrow[x]`

Comment: Thank you for this @user6014, this works just fine. Is there a way to adjust the size of the arrowhead using this method?

Comment: We're getting fast and loose with "documented" functionality, but try:
`ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}] /. Line[x__] :> Sequence[Arrowheads[.5], Arrow[x]]` (adjust size of arrowhead as needed). This might not be robust in _all_ situations.

Comment: This works just as I need it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

```
SeedRandom[1]
al = BezierFunction[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {14, 2}]];
be = BezierFunction[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}]];
```

You can temporarily redefine  `Line` as `Arrow` using `Block` and use `ParametricPlot`:

```
Block[{Line = Arrow}, 
  ParametricPlot[{al[t], be[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Graphics`

```
Graphics[{Thick, 
  MapThread[{#, Arrow[#2 /@ Subdivide[200]]} &, 
   {ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {al, be}}]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

> same picture

You can specify the size and position of the arrow heads using the directive `Arrowheads[{{size, pos}}]`:

```
Block[{Line = Arrow}, 
 ParametricPlot[{al[t], be[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{{.05, .75}}], PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, with `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{.05, .75}}], Thick, 
  MapThread[{#, Arrow[#2 /@ Subdivide[200]]} &, {ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {al, be}}]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 0):

To put arrows in a curve I usually use this code

```
ParametricPlot[...] /. Line[fig___] :> {Arrowheads[ConstantArray[0.06, 4]], Arrow[fig]};
```

[image]

The complete code:

```
r1[t_] = {-1 + 2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t], 0};
r2[t_] = {0, 2 + 2 Sinh[t], -2 + 2 Cosh[t]};
p1 = {0, 2 - Sqrt[1/2], 1 - Sqrt[1/2]}; p2 = {0, 2 + Sqrt[1/2], 
  1 + Sqrt[1/2]};
q1 = {0, 2 + Sqrt[1/2], 1 - Sqrt[1/2]}; q2 = {0, 2 - Sqrt[1/2], 
  1 + Sqrt[1/2]};
c2 = ParametricPlot3D[{0, 2 + Sqrt[1/2] Sinh[t], 
     1 + Sqrt[1/2] Cosh[t]}, {t, -2, 2},
    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[3.5]}] /. 
   Line[fig___] :> {Arrowheads[ConstantArray[0.06, 4]], Arrow[fig]};
c3 = ParametricPlot3D[{0, 2 + Sqrt[1/2] Sinh[t], 1 -
      Sqrt[1/2] Cosh[t]}, {t, -2, 2},
    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[3.5]}] /. 
   Line[fig___] :> {Arrowheads[ConstantArray[0.06, 4]], Arrow[fig]};

Graphics3D[{
  First@c2,
  First@c3,
  AbsolutePointSize[8.5], Orange, Point[{{0, 2, 1}}],
   Thick, Line[{ p1 - (p2 - p1), p1 + 2 (p2 - p1)}],
   Line[{ q1 - (q2 - q1), q1 + 2 (q2 - q1)}],
  Dashed, Thick, Gray, Line[{p1, q1, p2, q2, p1}]},
 Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```