# Adding arrow head at the end of ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have been trying to add an arrow head at the end (o even at some point) of a very simple parametric.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{-5 Sin[3 t], 5 Cos[3 t], t}, {t, 0, 15}]
```

But can not find a simple way to do it.

I have tried to merge plots using `Show[plot1,arrowh]` (for example), but this is not that elegant nor functional.

Any ideas?

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215834/58370).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi now that I understand it, yes, I did checked that question/answer before posting but didn't quite understood it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ParametricPlot3D` creates a `Line` which we can replace by an `Arrow`:

```
pl = ParametricPlot3D[{-5 Sin[3 t], 5 Cos[3 t], t}, {t, 0, 15}];
pl /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image: Output]

This will place arrowheads at fractions 0.1, 0.4, 0.7 and 1 along the curve:

```
arrowheads = Arrowheads@Transpose[{
     ConstantArray[Large, 4],
     {0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 1}
     }];
pl /. Line[pts_] :> {arrowheads, Arrow[pts]}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Perfect, just to deepen a bit, could you add multiple arrows of move it along the curve?

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60838/58370).

Comment: @C.Alexander As Rohit is showing it's really all about `Arrowheads`, but I added an example here as well.

Comment: You can also `Partition` the `Line`, e.g., `ParametricPlot3D[{-5 Sin[3 t], 5 Cos[3 t], t}, {t, 0, 15}] /. Line[pts__] :> Arrow /@ Partition[pts, 50, 49]`

Comment: Really helpful, I guess you can also change the arrow style in the same definition, right?

Comment: @C.Alexander yes, you can change the style in this way as well.

Comment: Or reverse the points: `ParametricPlot3D[{-5 Sin[3 t], 5 Cos[3 t], t}, {t, 0, 15}] /. 
 Line[pts__] :> Arrow /@ Partition[Reverse@pts, 50, 49]`